# Is the IoR of water exactly $4/3$?

Tags: optics, water, refraction

The index of refraction of water is commonly cited as $n \approx 1.33$, to varying numbers of decimal places. I've never seen a decimal expansion for this value with any digit other than $3$ past the decimal point.

Is it true that $n = \frac{4}{3}$ exactly?
That is, is this something we can derive from first principles (which seems potentially feasible, as water is a rather structurally simple compound), or is it experimental only?
If it's purely experimental, is there a more precise measurement that contains digits other than $3$ in the fractional part?

Comment: 1.3330 (589.29 nm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly not. The refractive index is a function of wavelength and temperature so it isn't a constant value anyway. If you're interested [this paper on the NIST web site](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd282.pdf) (1MB PDF) reports experimental measurements on the refractive index of water.

Actually I suppose there must be some combination of temperature and/or wavelength where the refractive index is exactly $\tfrac{4}{3}$ - it's greater in some conditions and lower in others so it must pass through the value $\tfrac{4}{3}$ somewhere.

Comment: True, assuming that the function is continuous... but we'd never know whether it is: once we go to exact quantities, we can't use any approximation, and our physical models are always approximations :)